# Extract subgroups from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table in a Pandas dataframe:

| Seconds | Color | Break | NaN | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.639588 | 123 | 4 | NaN | - |
| 1.149597 | 123 | 1 | NaN | - |
| 1.671333 | 123 | 2 | NaN | - |
| 1.802052 | 123 | 2 | NaN | - |
| 1.900091 | 123 | 1 | NaN | - |
| 2.031240 | 123 | 4 | NaN | - |
| 2.221477 | 123 | 3 | NaN | - |
| 2.631840 | 123 | 2 | NaN | - |
| 2.822245 | 123 | 1 | NaN | - |
| 2.911147 | 123 | 4 | NaN | - |
| 3.133344 | 123 | 1 | NaN | - |
| 3.531246 | 123 | 1 | NaN | - |
| 3.822389 | 123 | 1 | NaN | - |
| 3.999389 | 123 | 2 | NaN | - |
| 4.327990 | 123 | 4 | NaN | - |

I'm trying to extract subgroups of the column labelled as 'Break' in such a way that the first and last item of each group is a '4'. So, the first group should be: [4,1,2,2,1,4]; the second group: [4,3,2,1,4]; the third group: [4,1,1,1,2,4]. The last '4' of each group is the first '4' of the following group.

I have the following code:

```
groups = []

def extract_phrases_between_four(data, new_group = []):
   
   row_iterator = data.iterrows()
   for i, row in row_iterator: #for index, row in row_iterator
       
       if row['Break_Level_Annotation'] != '4': 
           new_group.append(row['Break_Level_Annotation']) 
       
           
       if row['Break_Level_Annotation'] == '4': 
           new_group = []
           new_group.append(row['Break_Level_Annotation'])
           
       groups.append(new_group)
   return groups
```

but my output is:

```
[[4,1,1,1,2],[4,1,1,1,2],[4,1,1,1,2],[4,1,1,1,2],[4,1,1,1,2],[4,3,2,1],[4,3,2,1],[4,3,2,1],[4,3,2,1],[4,1,1,1,2],[4,1,1,1,2],[4,1,1,1,2],[4,1,1,1,2]].
```

It's returning the same new_group repeatedly as many times as there are items in each new_group, while at the same time not including the final '4' of each new_group.

I've tried to move around the code but I can't seem to understand what the problem is. How can I get each new_group to include its first and final '4' and for the new_group to be included only once in the array 'groups'?

Answer (score 3):

IIUC you can extract the index and use list comprehension:

```
s = df.loc[df["Break"].eq(4)].index

print ([df.loc[np.arange(x, y+1), "Break"].tolist() for x, y in zip(s, s[1:])])

[[4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1, 4], [4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in each step in the `for` loop, you are adding `new_group` to `groups`, although you are still adding elements to `new_group`. You need to execute `groups.append(new_group)` inside the second `if` statement.

Also, pay attention that you can iterate directly the `"Break"` column values instead of the whole dataframe and accessing each time to get the value.

I rewrote the code a little bit, and it looks as follows:

```py
groups = []
new_group = []
for i in data["Break"]:
    new_group.append(i)
    if i == 4:
        if len(new_group) > 1:
            groups.append(new_group)
            new_group = [4]

print(groups)
```

And there is the result:

```
[[4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1, 4], [4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4]]
```